# WPF-App Embedd WPF window/control from other AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, appdomain

I have an assembly which generates a Form (it is a client-software). I can build an app getting and starting (Show) that form without any problem. But I cannot start that Form twice because the assembly does not provide a clean capsuled solution. Every second start it would crash because several things will not initialize successful a second time. Unfortunately that assembly cannot be modified.

Now I have put that in a seperate AppDomain to be able to unload that assembly. This works fine and the hosting application can now start that Form multiple times.

Now the **problem** is: I have a WPF-app which should not show that assembly's Form, it should contain it in one of its own windows. The WinForms Form of the assembly is already in a WindowsFormHost and WPF-Window (with AssemblyAppDomain). But I cannot assign the WPF-Window as Content of one of the main WPF-app-windows. It is in the AssemblyAppDomain AppDomain (and object space is not shared with that).

As far as I searched up to now it should be possible to establish a connection between two WPF windows in different AppDomains because that is kind of the way System.AddIn works. Should work with a *Pipeline*, *Contract* and *FrameworkElementAdapter*. I am somewhat stuck and any more specific hints will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the [docs about WPF addins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909794.aspx)? Also check out [this example](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/10/12/managed-addin-framework-system.addin-with-wpf.aspx).

Comment: The example looks much better than anything I found before. I'll give it a try to use the complete AddIn-functionality.

Comment: Your example link and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909974.aspx helped me a lot. I was wondering how to use the pipeline mechanism without having to implement the complete addon-functionality. In the end once you know it using System.AddIn is not too difficult and on the other hand very powerful. Thanks for directing my mind in the right direction ;)